# Can only moderators change answers to comments on behalf of new users?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, not-an-answer, convert-to-comment

So I was carrying out my latest mission in life of removing all "Microsoft" tags from questions tagged "Microsoft" AND "Excel" and came upon this 4 year old question:

[macro to re-arrange data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828916/microsoft-excel-2010-rearranging-macro)

The 2nd answer is from the OP, and to my mind isn't an answer, should have been flagged as such, and converted into a comment.

Of course, the OP at that time didn't have enough Rep to leave it as a comment...

So I flagged it for Moderator attention, asking the mod to change it to a comment on the other answer...as it does in fact clarify information.

Bearing in mind that it's 4 years old, and the OP hasn't been back, am I being too kind here, should I have just slapped a downvote on it, flagged it as *not an answer* and moved on (time is after all, money and cigarettes)?

With recent questions I guess I would try to be a little kinder, ask the mods to convert it to a comment if the poor little lamb / guy doesn't have enough rep, but on a 4 year old question perhaps it's not worth the extra effort?

**EDIT**

So after checking when [jakekimds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3161440/jakekimds) made the point about the differnet user profiles, I am guessing that the OP added the answer from his mobile after inadvertently creating a new account...

In which case it makes even more sense to change it to a comment, if it will fit (length wise)

Comment: Users can always comment on their own questions regardless of reputation.

Comment: @animuson: Thanks, before I go off the deep end and ask for a new feature of being able to convert an answer into a comment - has this already been asked and slapped down, or asked and approved for high-rep or mods?

Comment: There's one for the review queues: [New review queue needs a “Convert to comment” option](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143961/new-review-queue-needs-a-convert-to-comment-option) - I'm not sure if there are others floating around.

Comment: I'm not sure if the answerer is the OP. They have different user profiles and IDs

Comment: @jakekimds: I think the OP opened a new account by mistake using his mobile, that's why it wouldn't let him post as a comment, and why he looks like a different person, but from the content of the answer, I judge it to be the OP